# cakephp 2.10 get data without model class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Cakephp 2.10 ?

```
$text = $this->PrivacyPolicy->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'title', 'description')
));
```

How PrivacyPolicy is becoming a model role as there is no Model class in the files or relation with the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Magic and unicorn dust... otherwise known as [**naming conventions**](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) and auto-models.

If no concrete model class can be found, CakePHP will create an instance of the `AppModel` base class instead, which will lookup the database table based on the the model name that you've used. So in your case the `AppModel` instance will look up the data in `privacy_policies` (lowercased, underscored, plural variant of the model name).

Quote from the docs:

> CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot find a corresponding file in /app/Model. This also means that if your model file isn’t named correctly (for instance, if it is named ingredient.php or Ingredients.php rather than Ingredient.php), CakePHP will use an instance of AppModel rather than your model file (which CakePHP assumes is missing). If you’re trying to use a method you’ve defined in your model, or a behavior attached to your model, and you’re getting SQL errors that are the name of the method you’re calling, it’s a sure sign that CakePHP can’t find your model and you need to check the file names, your application cache, or both.

**https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models.html#understanding-models**